# Create horizontal draggable list in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list

How can I create a draggable list that scroll horizontally?[image: example of drag]

For example in this image I would like to move "Celik" before "Buongiorno".

I am currently using the latest available version of SwiftUI

I expect that is required to write something like

```
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
    HStack(spacing: 5) {
         ForEach(viewModel.bench, id: \.id) { player in
              PlayerCardView(player: player, selectedPlayerId: $viewModel.selectedPlayerFromBench)
              .onDrag({
                   // Should I implement the logic here?
          })
    }
}
```

Since I can't use Swift List built-in functionalities how can solve my issue?

How can I update to position of the dragged item in the viewModel.bench array?

Comment: Why can't you use "Swift List built-in functionalities"?

Comment: Swift list only displays vertical rows I need a horizontal list

Comment: Are trying to make a horizontal list view that allows you to rearrange the items in the view?

Comment: Reorder data model array stored as a State var when dragging ends